# Qt value from lineEdit and isChecked from QCheckBox not working as expected

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a `QMessageBox` pop up when I press a submit button, which works fine, however the message inside is dependent based on whether some checkboxes are checked, and on the value of the line-edit, as such:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow();
.
.
.
QPushButton but_submit("Submit");
QMessageBox msg_submit;

// The following will be so that we can get the val of the GPA and then add it
// To the full message that will contain the info of person
QString submit_string = "Hello, here's the summary: \n";
submit_string += "Here\'s your value: " +  line_misc[0]->text() +  ".\n";
if (chk_art->isChecked())
    submit_string += "Art major!";
msg_submit.setText(submit_string);
.
. 
.
QObject::connect(&but_submit, SIGNAL(clicked()), &msg_submit, SLOT(exec()));

w->show();
return a.exec();
```

Everything that is not in the code here I have defined or initialized, and I don't have any warnings or errors when I run the code, all is well, everything is displayed, but it's like nothing is connected.

The message box (`msg_submit`) appears but the message is

> Hello, here's the summary:
>   Here's your value: .

When I'm really expecting to see a number, or the art major comment as well if I have the checkbox (`chk_art`) checked, but I do not, unfortunately.

I've gone through the docs and tried variations, such as using a `spinBox`, and using the property function `value()` to just get the value and wrapping it in `QString::number()`, but no matter what I change the value to, it's like `setValue` property isn't called when I change the value, or the slot `valueChanged()` doesn't run either.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: what is `line_misc`?

Comment: @eyllanesc line_misc is a lineEdit array with 3 different ones that were initialized and added to a layout. I should have emphasized that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you should update `submit_string` after click event emits.
Can try with lambda function

```
QObject::connect(&but_submit, &QPushButton::clicked,
        [&line_misc, &chk_art](){
        QMessageBox msg_submit;
        QString submit_string = "Hello, here's the summary: \n";
        submit_string += "Here\'s your value: " + line_misc[0]->text() + ".\n";
        if (chk_art->isChecked())
            submit_string += "Art major!";
        msg_submit.setText(submit_string);
        msg_submit.exec();
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error when i try that, i also tried to switch the &QPushButton::clicked... here's the error -- no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QPushButton*, void (QAbstractButton::*)(), main(int, char**)::<lambda()>)'
o click, as well as using SIGNAL(clicked())

Comment: I updated the code. Pass reference to lambda function `[&line_misc, &chk_art]`. Btw, Are you using c++11 or higher version?